# Outlook 2010 Calendar looping on Windows 10

Tags: windows, microsoft-outlook-2010

Suddenly, this afternoon, Outlook 2010 loops each time I click the Calendar link. All other functions of Outlook work OK. There's a circle in the middle of the display. I searched the web and found no solution.

Answer (score 0):

As mysteriously as it started this problem mysteriously resolved itself. I found no Win 10 updates since 11/9/16 on my machine. The only thing I did was a repair of Office 2010, but that did not immediately fix the problem.